# Pagecolor with a angle of 45 degrees from bottom left to top right

Tags: tikz-pgf, pagecolor

I think it is not difficult,  but I do not achieve it. I want a page, that has two colors, I tried with tikz but the problems were the angles.

I need something like this:

[image]

Without the text. I basically want a two-color page with 45 degrees!

Comment: How did you create the output you show? What should the dimensions of the page be? It looks like it should be a square? You can try `\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{ \fill[red] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east) -- (current page.south east) -- cycle; }`.

Comment: That actually worked! thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `current page` node created by Ti*k*Z. This might require at least two compilation runs (of course, since A4 is not a square, the angle of the triangle is not 45 degrees in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{ \fill[red] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east) -- (current page.south east) -- cycle; }

% other stuff

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want this to be a background for all pages in your document, you can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{ \fill[red] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east) -- (current page.south east) -- cycle; }%
}

\begin{document}

% ...

\end{document}
```